# font issue in watermark text on image in php

Tags: php, text, watermark

I have problem in watermark text on image in php 
my code is

```
$im='myimage.jepeg'
header ("Content-type: image/jpeg");

$string = "text on image";

$font = 4;

$width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string) ;

$height = imagefontheight($font) ;

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($im);

$x = imagesx($im) - $width ;

$y = imagesy($im) - $height;

$backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);

$textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0,0);

imagettftext ($im, $font, $x, $y, $string, $textColor);

imagejpeg($im);
```

i have change fonts size but can't work

Comment: i think its jpeg not jepeg

Answer (score 0):

There is no extension `jepeg` as you are using in your script. So replace the below script

```
$im='myimage.jepeg';
```

To

```
$im='myimage.jpeg';
```

Also you need to careful about semicolon `;` php script will be stop and return error if missed to put the semicolon at the end of script.

Comment: i am generally write image name my issue is fonts